# Pasting into next blank cell in specific column with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to copy and paste two ranges from one sheet to another.  The first copy and paste works fine, but the 2nd keeps giving me "Application defined or object defined error".  The second range will copy, but won't paste.  I'm trying to paste it into the next empty cell in column M.  My vba code is below, any advice is appreciated, I'm still learning VBA.

```
`Sub CopyAtoKIntoBankData()

' CopyAtoKIntoBankData Macro
  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

 'This is my source for copying
  Set copySheet = Worksheets("Data Conversion")
'This is destination for pasting
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Bank Data")

  'copy columns a:k into bank data, first set of data this works fine
  copySheet.Range("A2:K100").Copy
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  'Topaste colum M from Data conversion to Bank Data
  copySheet.Range("m2:m100").Copy
  If IsEmpty(pasteSheet.Range("m5038")) Then
    pasteSheet.Range("M5038").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
  Else
  paste
Sheet.Cells.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(x1up).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  End If
  
End Sub``
```

Comment: There is a lot room for improvements in your code, but the first thing you need to do is to use `Option Explicit` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement). Then you will quickly find out that there is something not right with `x1up` - it is `xlUp`.

Comment: One more, `paste Sheet.Cells.Range("M" & Rows.Count) ...` `pasteSheet` is accidently seperated into two lines. btw, you don't need `Cells` before `Range(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values

```vb
Option Explicit ' at the top of each module!
```

**Basic (`.PasteSpecial`)**

- slow
- needs `Application.CutCopyMode = False`
- messes up the selection on the destination worksheet

```vb
Sub CopyConversionToBankBasic()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
  
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet: Set wsCopy = wb.Worksheets("Data Conversion")
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet: Set wsPaste = wb.Worksheets("Bank Data")
    
    Dim rgCopy As Range, cellPaste As Range
    
    Set rgCopy = wsCopy.Range("A2:K100")
    Set cellPaste = wsPaste.Cells(wsPaste.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
  
    rgCopy.Copy
    cellPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  
    Set rgCopy = rgCopy.EntireRow.Columns("M")
    Set cellPaste = cellPaste.EntireRow.Columns("M")
  
    rgCopy.Copy
    cellPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  
End Sub
```

**Advanced (*Copy by Assignment*)**

- fast
- needs the destination to be of the same size as the source (`.Resize`)
- doesn't mess up the selection on the destination worksheet

```vb
Sub CopyConversionToBank()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
  
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Data Conversion")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Bank Data")
    
    Dim srg As Range, dcell As Range
    
    Set srg = sws.Range("A2:K100")
    Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    dcell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
    
    Set srg = srg.EntireRow.Columns("M")
    Set dcell = dcell.EntireRow.Columns("M")
  
    dcell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count).Value = srg.Value ' one column only

End Sub
```